# Performing submissions on Orbeon 4.9

Tags: xml, orbeon

Having some trouble performing submissions after upgrading to `Orbeon 4.9`.

The following submission was used as example:

```
<xf:submission action="http://localhost:7001/orbeon49/getValuesServlet"
id="OPEN_DOCUMENT"
method="post"
ref="instance('fr-form-instance')"
replace="instance">
</xf:submission>
```

And to call the submission, this code was used:

```
<xf:action ev:event="xforms-ready">
     <xf:send submission="OPEN_DOCUMENT"/>
</xf:action>
```

The submission is supposed to call a `servlet` which resides within the `Orbeon` application application that responds with an `XML` that updates the instance `XML`. In version 4.9 the servlet is never called and the submission fails. 
In version 4.6 this was working fine.

I reverted to version 4.7 just to try if a higher version than 4.6 makes a difference and it worked fine on 4.7 as well.

So, does this mean that the way we need to call submissions on 4.9 has changed?

Comment: Update: Moving the servlet out of the Orbeon application allows the submissions to occur. So, it seems like calls to servlets within the Orbeon application are blocked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to the implementation of [internal requests](http://blog.orbeon.com/2015/01/saying-goodbye-to-internal-http.html). Orbeon Forms, since 4.7, considers requests to itself as internal, and does not use an actual HTTP connection. However this will not work to call a servlet which is within the Orbeon web app.

Orbeon Forms guesses internal requests by creating an absolute URL, and then checking whether it matches a path to itself, such as `http://localhost:8080/orbeon/`

You could trick it to still cause that servlet by using an absolute URL such as, maybe `http://127.0.0.1:8080/orbeon/`.